# Is there any compact and elegant way in C# to simultaneously iterate through two lists?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

So I have a few pieces of code where I do stuff like

```
        List<ParameterInfo> theseParams = this.Action.GetParameters().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList(),
                            otherParams = other.Action.GetParameters().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
        if(theseParams.Count != otherParams.Count)
            return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < theseParams.Count; ++i)
        {
            ParameterInfo thisParam = theseParams[i],
                          otherParam = otherParams[i];
            if(thisParam.Name != otherParam.Name)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
```

and I'm wondering if instead there's a compact way to iterate through to lists at once?

Comment: Check out [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Sure just use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Enumerable.All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
return theseParams.Count == otherParams.Count
    && theseParams.Zip(otherParams, (t,o) => new {These = t, Other =o})
    .All(x => x.These.Name == x.Other.Name);
```

Comment: Importnat note, this does not handle the `if(theseParams.Count != otherParams.Count)` check, that part still needs to be in the code. Zip behaves similar to `for(int i = 0; i < theseParams.Count && i < otherParams.Count; ++i)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Missed that, fixed now.

Comment: Although the question is duplicate, this answer deserves upvote:)